# implement an object that holds x seats in y rows

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the best way to implement an object that holds x rows with y seats? Would it be to use a dictionary object, such as

```
object={'row1:"2", "row2:"2","row3":"4"}
```

And then reference each row if I where to update number of seats?
Or are there any better way of implementing this?

/Andy.l

Comment: It depends on how you are going to use it. obj[row] and obj[row] = x are the only operations you are planning to use on the object?

Comment: Certainly you can implemente such an object and add a lot of functionality into it - please state what functionality you want - like eing able to mark whch seats are reserved and so on. Just noting down the existence of seats in each row can be done as you are doing, or using the list method by @Luke

Comment: What does it mean to "hold x seats"? Do you need to store information about each seat, or do you only care about the count of the seats in each row?

Comment: All I actually need is to know how many seats are available at each row, and update the number if any seats are reserved. So I do not need much functionality, except it should be easy to implement in a class, if possible. -Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you're doing is tracking rows and seats, you could do it with a simple array:

```
rows = [2,2,4]
```

Row 1 is `rows[0]` with 2 seats, Row 3 is `rows[2]` with 4 seats, and so on.

Comment: This seems like a simple, yet good way to do it. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the operations you need to perform on a row, you may find it better to create a `Row` class and put instances of that in the dictionary.

```
class Row(object):
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.maxseats = num
    self.currseats = num
  def reserve(self.num):
    self.currseats -= num
   ...

theatre = {'row1': Row(26), 'row2': Row(24), ...}
```

Comment: I'm interesting solution, but I'm not quite sure how I would implement this. I'm no Python Expert:-)